# Can we use subethasmtp with postfix?

Tags: postfix-mta

is it possible to use postfix with subethasmtp
so that postfix can deliver emails to subethasmtp and it handle those emails ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you would use transport_maps to route certain mails or whole domains to subethasmtp.

```
transport_maps = hash:etc/postfix/transport
```

containing stuff like:

```
mydomain.com    smtp:[ipaddress]:port
```

where subethasmtp must be listening on ipaddress and port.